# Mixing jQuery, prototype and 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project that uses some JS prototyping and jQuery.

My issue, I believe, is how 'this' is being used.

In my code, I have some jQuery in a function that I will be prototyping. The jQuery looks like this:(in this code, 'target' is a jQuery object passed when IMAGE_UPLOADER is first created.)

```
document.getElementById(target.find('.file_selector').prop('id')).addEventListener("change", this.FileSelectHandler, false);
```

In this event listener, there is a function called FileSelectHandler. This function is being called just fine. However, within this function, there is a call to a second function. Here is a short version of the function:

```
FILE_UPLOADER.prototype.FileSelectHandler = function(e) {

this.FileDragHover(e);
 }
```

This is where the error comes up. JS is complaining that the function 'FileDragHover' does not exist. It, of course DOES exist and is defined as follows:

```
FILE_UPLOADER.prototype.FileDragHover = function(e) {}
```

I hope this is enough info to understand the problem. If not, please let me know and I can add more.

Comment: `this` is probably the element, not the instance. Try `console.log(this)` that should give you a tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass the custom execution handler to the event handler, `this` inside the event handler refers to the dom element where the listener is attached - it is the same as [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) but jQuery version [supports IE < 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility).

```
document.getElementById(target.find('.file_selector').prop('id')).addEventListener("change", $.proxy(this.FileSelectHandler, this), false);
```

The handler registration can be simplified using jQuery to

```
target.find('.file_selector').change($.proxy(this.FileSelectHandler, this))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Arun and the introduction to a very useful little bit of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If an object `obj` has a function `func` and you do `obj.func()` the function is called in context of `obj` where `this` in that function then referes to `obj`.

If you however do something like this:

```
var callback = obj.func;
callback();
```

Then `callback` is not called in the context of `obj` anymore. For browsers the context is then `window`. This is what is happening if you pass the function as callback to the `addEventListener`.
Depending how your callback is used it can be *called* with another context, for event listeners it is the DOM element, so `this` in your code refers to the DOM element.

To solve this problem you can used [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (you need to check the browser support if it is usable for you or use a polyfill for it, that can be found on the mdn page), you can use [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) or create a closure and maintain the context yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` variable refers to the invoking object not the object that the method is declared on. So if I have `someObject.someFunction();` then someObject is the invoking object and the value of `this` in the function.

To demonstrate:

```
var obj1 = {
  name:"obj1",
  say:function(){
    console.log(this.name);
  }
};
var obj2 = {name:"obj2"};
obj2.say = obj1.say;
obj2.say()//logs obj2
```

In the above code say was declared on obj1 but invoked from obj2.

More on the this value, constructor functions and prototype [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).